# PyTrends/Google-Trends-API (npm) - Getting Google Trends Embed Data rather than the CSV

Tags: google-api, google-trends, google-data

I have been trying to use these two different api's however occasionally get inconsistent data with massive gaps & spikes. When comparing with Google Trends website I see that I am actually getting the embed link data rather than the pure csv data and the two are completely different on certain searches. Is this Google doing something clever to stop external api's?

I'm hoping to receive the csv data rather than the embed link data. Additionally I notice I occasionally get a blocked message after a few searches and have to wait a while to get a successful response (Separate issue but worth noting).